# Preprocessor macro to target Interface Builder not available to OS X?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, macros, interface-builder

I have an `IB_DESIGNABLE` custom `NSView` subclass. When drawing, I want my view to perform a method only when it's being run in Interface Builder. I looked this up, and Apple's documentation states:

> You can use the preprocessor macro `TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` to specify
>   code for inclusion with or exclusion from your custom view class.
>
> ```
> - (void)connectToMyServer {
> #if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
>     // connect to the server
> #else
>     // don't connect; instead, draw my custom view
> #endif 
> }
> ```

I jumped over to my code, and added the following to one of my methods:

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
[self myMethodForInterfaceBuilder];
#endif
```

Immediately, I got the following error:

> ... /MyCustomView.m:134:8: Use of undeclared identifier 'TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER'

This leads me to believe that the `TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` preprocessor macro is only good for Xcode targets using the iOS SDK. Am I correct in this assumption, or have I overlooked something? Any advice would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That macro is only defined when Interface Builder is building your code. Therefore the correct usage is this:

```
#ifdef TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
... // for Interface Builder 
#else
... // regular behavior
#endif
```

Comment: Did you mean `#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` instead of `#ifdef TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER`? As my question is a bit dated now, I honestly can't remember what I was trying to do. However, I've since built multiple classes that work with Interface Builder using the code I posted in the question (as well as what I think you meant in the answer), so I'm not really sure what the problem was. Knowing the stability of Xcode over the years, I'd venture to say what I was experiencing was a bug.

Comment: Nope. I meant `ifdef`. The TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER macro is defined only if the code is being built by IB. At least that was my experience.

Comment: Oh, man … I'm not too bright. I just realized that this question was in regard to Objective-C (not Swift). I've been doing so much Swift stuff, I thought, surely this guy means `#if` and not `#ifdef`. Haha. I apologize. I just set up a little Objective-C project and your macro works as promised. I guess after 3 years, we can finally mark this question as answered! Thanks, mate.